# Creating a Composable Confirm Dialog Box

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable called ConfirmationDialog defined as so

```
@Composable
fun ConfirmationDialog(
    title: String,
    message: String,
    cancelText: String,
    confirmText: String,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit
) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        title = {
            Text(text = title)
        },
        text = {
            Text(text = message)
        },
        confirmButton = {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    onConfirm()
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = confirmText)
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            Button(onClick = {
                onDismiss()
            }
            ) {
                Text(text = cancelText)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

In my NoteScreen, I need to call this dialog. But i get an error that says

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @Composable function

This is how i implement it

```
@Composable
fun NoteScreen(
    state: NoteState,
    onEvent: (NoteEvent) -> Unit
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                title = { /*TODO*/ },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            onEvent(NoteEvent.NavigateBack)
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "navigate back"
                        )
                    }
                },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            ConfirmationDialog(
                                title = "Confirm Action",
                                message = "Would you like to delete this message?",
                                cancelText = "Cancel",
                                confirmText = "Ok",
                                onConfirm = {
                                    onEvent(NoteEvent.DeleteNote)
                                }, onDismiss = {

                                }
                            )
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Delete,
                            contentDescription = "delete")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    ) { padding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(padding)
                .padding(
                    horizontal = 20.dp,
                    vertical = 15.dp
                ),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
              OutlinedTextField (
                  value = state.title,
                  onValueChange = {
                      onEvent(NoteEvent.TitleChange(it))
                  },
                  placeholder = {
                      Text(text = "Title")
                  }
              )
            OutlinedTextField (
                value = state.content,
                onValueChange = {
                    onEvent(NoteEvent.ContentChange(it))
                },
                placeholder = {
                    Text(text = "Content")
                }

            )
            OutlinedTextField (
                value = state.timeStamp,
                onValueChange = {
                    onEvent(NoteEvent.TimeStampChange(it))
                },
                placeholder = {
                    Text(text = "Time Stamp")
                },
            )
            
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            ) {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        onEvent(NoteEvent.Save)
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
                        .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Save")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This happens when I invoke the ConfirmationDialog.

Answer (score 0):

The lamdba function that you assign to `onClick` does not have a Composable scope. To show the Dialog after clicking, you need to introduce a separate variable instead:

```
var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

Extend your Dialog by one boolean parameter and only show the Dialog if the variable is `true`:

```
@Composable
fun ConfirmationDialog(
    show: Boolean,
    title: String,
    message: String,
    cancelText: String,
    confirmText: String,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit
) {
    if (show) {
        AlertDialog(
            // ...
        )
    }
}
```

Include the `ConfirmationDialog` anywhere in your `NoteScreen` Composable:

```
ConfirmationDialog(
   show = showDialog,
   title = "Confirm Action",
   // ...
)
```

Finally, change the variable value in your `onClick` function to show the Dialog:

```
onClick = { showDialog = true }
```

This will make the Dialog show.